# Python regex to pull FQDN from syslog server

Tags: python, regex, syslog, fqdn

I'm trying to build a regex to parse our syslogs.  I was asked to account for each server that uses the service.  I wrote a simple regex to pull out the FQDN, but it seems to be consuming too much of the line...

```
>>> string = "2010-12-13T00:00:02-05:00 <local3.info> suba1.suba2.example.com named[29959]: client 192.168.11.53#54608: query: subb1.subb2.example.com"
>>> regex = re.compile("\s.*?\.example\.com ")
>>> r = regex.search(string)
>>> r
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x896dae0bbf9e6bf0>

# Run findall
>>> regex.findall(string)
[u' <local3.info> suba1.suba2.example.com ', u' client 192.168.11.53#54608: query: subb1.subb2.example.com ']
```

As you can see the findall with .* is too generic and the regex ends up consuming to much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replacing `\s` with `\b` and the `.*?` with `\S` will do it.

```
>>> regex = re.compile(r'\b\S*\.example\.com')
>>> regex.findall(string)
[u'suba1.suba2.example.com', u'subb1.subb2.example.com']
```

Answer (score 0):

The regex

```
r"query: ([\w\.]+)"
```

would grab the end from [...] query on and then you can use a unnamed group look-up to give you just the domain name.

If this isn't the output you need, can you elaborate on the desired output (as a data structure. I took a guess for this).

The python code might look like:

```
match = re.search(r"query: ([\w.]+)", string, re.IGNORECASE | re.MULTILINE)
if match:
    result = match.group(1)
else:
    result = ""
```

result would contain

```
subb1.subb2.example.com
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import re

s = """2010-12-13T00:00:02-05:00 <local3.info> 
    suba1.suba2.example.com named[29959]: 
    client 192.168.11.53#54608: query: subb1.subb2.example.com"""

pattern = re.compile("[\S.]+.example.com")

print pattern.findall(s)
# => ['suba1.suba2.example.com', 'subb1.subb2.example.com']
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I forgot about \S ... That works perfect for space delimited lines.

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
regex = re.compile("\s\S*?\.example\.com ")
```